# Warble Custom war file name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, war, warbler

I am using Wabler gem to generate the war file for our Ruby on Rails application. By default, it generates a WAR file named the Rails project home directory name by default.

I would like to know if it is possible to specify custom war file name instead of the default project home directory name.

Thanks
Noman A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found answer to my question, so sharing with all who might need it.

File to modify:

warble.rb

For our application, this resides inside [project_dir]/config/

This file would have a section like:

```
 Warbler::Config.new do |config|
   .....
   .....
 end
```

Add the following line to specify custom war/jar file name (without extension):

```
 config.jar_name = "testname"
```

So, the segment would look like:

```
 Warbler::Config.new do |config|
   .....
   .....
   config.jar_name = "testname" 
 end
```

**Note**: The "**....**" shown above are not part of the actual configuration, I have replaced original values for example purpose.

Now, when I run warble war/ rake war, it generates war file as "testname.war"

Hope this might help another newbie like me!

Thanks

Noman A.

Answer (score 0):

Add config/warble.rb file.

```
Warbler::Config.new do |config|
  config.war_name = "test_war_name"
end
```

Edit: `config.war_name` is deprecated, see logged [here](https://github.com/jruby/warbler/blob/master/lib/warbler/config.rb?246)

```
# Deprecated
def war_name
  $stderr.puts "config.war_name deprecated; replace with config.jar_name" #:nocov:
  jar_name                  #:nocov:
end
```

Use the following:

```
 Warbler::Config.new do |config|
  config.jar_name = "test_war_name"
 end
```